# How to read datasheet of BJT by On Semi?

Tags: datasheet

[image]

I'm now reading the [datasheet of the 2N4401 by OnSemi.](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/2n4401-d.pdf)  Why is hFE so low in this graph? hFE = IC/IB, right? hFE is just 0 - 3.0 over a wide range of IC.
On the previous page, they give a large number of hFE in DC current gain row.

[image]

Can anyone explain this?

Comment: On the graph's Y-axis, you're missing the word **normalized**. Do you need that explained?

Answer (score 8):

\$h_{FE}\$ will vary from transistor to transistor. The vertical graph axis contains the text "*normalized* current gain". Inspecting the graph shows that the curve for 25 degrees C and Vce=1 V intersects the "normalized current gain" of 1 at exactly Ic = 10 mA. So, if you know the \$h_{FE}\$ of a transistor at 25 degrees C, Vce=1 V and Ic=10 mA, you can uses the chart to estimate what \$h_{FE}\$ might be at some other operating point with a different temperature, Vce or Ic.

Answer (score 7):

Figure 15 displays \$h_{FE}\$ as a normalized value relative to \$V_{CE} = 1.0V\$, \$I_C= 10mA\$ at a temperature of 25 degrees Celsuis. The data line in the table lists this value at \$h_{FE}=80\$.

So multiply the entries on the chart by 80 to get the actual value.

This is a common method in data sheets. The y=axis label indicates that it is normalized